# B-flick movie where a man is searching for parts to repair his robo-wife

Tags: story-identification, b-movies

I vaguely recall a made-for-tv? movie (25ish years ago) and I remember some plot points but I can't seem to track it down by googling. I may be mis-remembering some of the details.

A corporate suit comes home and starts to get romantic on the kitchen floor with his wife but the dishwasher overflows and water spills out on to the floor. Sparks fly and low and behold, his "perfect" wife is revealed (to the audience) as an android. He's told that she's a (rare? obsolete?) model, and there's no parts to repair her. But there may be some in this lawless-dystopian-post-apocalyptic-wasteland-type area.

So he hires this guide (female, red hair?) to help him search for the parts. They end up falling for each other. They eventually find the parts and repair robo-wife, but he realizes that her companionship is shallow compared to the hard-living and very real woman he hired to help find the parts and I seem to remember that he leaves the android behind as explosions are happening.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like [**Cherry 2000**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_2000) (1987).

In the [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKkdgnDu3MA) you can see the romantic intercourse on the kitchen's wet floor between the guy and his robot wife and the red-haired guide (Melanie Griffith) who helps him in the search.

Comment: based on the wikipedia link, 100% this is it. how a wet kitchen floor could be a hazard to an android is beyond me -- if that caused a major malfunction, how many little things would cause minor problems, in particular say behavioral issues? science fiction movies can be so terrible when it comes down to science/technology.

Comment: That's it. Thanks!

Comment: @releseabe- in hindsight, he was lucky he didn't get electrocuted.